# horizontal auto scrolling div using elements.scroll javascript

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I have a div with a few items in it.
I want to loop back to the first item after automatically horizontally scrolling to the last item.
In essence, it will function as an endless auto carousel.
I used setInterval and scrollLeft to get to the last item.
However, how can I loop back to the first item when it reaches the last item.
my implementation link: https://jsfiddle.net/3zd012ch/

html code:

```
<div style="position: relative; border: 2px solid #878787; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px;">
  <button class="carousel-btn prev" style="position:absolute;z-index:99;top:47%;transform:translateY(-50%);height:60%;opacity:1;cursor:pointer;left:0rem;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);width:20px">&#8656;</button>
  <button class="carousel-btn next" style="position:absolute;z-index:99;top:47%;transform:translateY(-50%);height:60%;cursor:pointer;right:0rem;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);width:20px">&#8658;</button>
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; margin-bottom:0;">
    <h3 style="margin:0">Related Videos</h3>
    
    
  </div>
  <div id="slider" style="position:relative;width:100%; height:200px; overflow: hidden; overflow-x: scroll; display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap;justify-content: space-between;">


    
      <a href="https:///${route}/${videosList[i].content_id}/${sourceLanguage}" target="_blank">
                            <div style="position: relative; 
                              width: 320px; 
                              height: 180px; 
                              border-radius: 8px;
                              overflow: hidden; 
                              margin:10px;
                              margin-left:0px;
                              background: url('${videosList[i].thumbnail}'); 
                              background-size: cover; 
                              background-position-x: center; 
                              background-position-y: center;">
                                  <div style="position: absolute; 
                                    bottom:0px; 
                                    height:100px; 
                                    width:100%; 
                                    background: black; 
                                    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);"></div>
                                  <img src="https://www.ramiksadana.com/images/play.png" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; left:110px; top: 30px; margin:0!important;" />
                                  <p style="position: absolute; bottom:0px; color: white; margin: 0px 10px; margin-bottom: 15px !important; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; text-overflow-y: ellipsis;">
                                    ${videosList[i].title}
                                  </p>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                          <a href="/${route}/${videosList[i].content_id}/${sourceLanguage}" target="_blank">
                            <div style="position: relative; 
                              width: 320px; 
                              height: 180px; 
                              border-radius: 8px;
                              overflow: hidden; 
                              margin:10px;
                              margin-left:0px;
                              background: url('${videosList[i].thumbnail}'); 
                              background-size: cover; 
                              background-position-x: center; 
                              background-position-y: center;">
                                  <div style="position: absolute; 
                                    bottom:0px; 
                                    height:100px; 
                                    width:100%; 
                                    background: black; 
                                    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);"></div>
                                  <img src="https://www.ramiksadana.com/images/play.png" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; left:110px; top: 30px; margin:0!important;" />
                                  <p style="position: absolute; bottom:0px; color: white; margin: 0px 10px; margin-bottom: 15px !important; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; text-overflow-y: ellipsis;">
                                    ${videosList[i].title}
                                  </p>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                          <a href="/${route}/${videosList[i].content_id}/${sourceLanguage}" target="_blank">
                            <div style="position: relative; 
                              width: 320px; 
                              height: 180px; 
                              border-radius: 8px;
                              overflow: hidden; 
                              margin:10px;
                              margin-left:0px;
                              background: url('${videosList[i].thumbnail}'); 
                              background-size: cover; 
                              background-position-x: center; 
                              background-position-y: center;">
                                  <div style="position: absolute; 
                                    bottom:0px; 
                                    height:100px; 
                                    width:100%; 
                                    background: black; 
                                    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);"></div>
                                  <img src="https://www.ramiksadana.com/images/play.png" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; left:110px; top: 30px; margin:0!important;" />
                                  <p style="position: absolute; bottom:0px; color: white; margin: 0px 10px; margin-bottom: 15px !important; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; text-overflow-y: ellipsis;">
                                    ${videosList[i].title}
                                  </p>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                          <a href="\/${route}/${videosList[i].content_id}/${sourceLanguage}" target="_blank">
                            <div style="position: relative; 
                              width: 320px; 
                              height: 180px; 
                              border-radius: 8px;
                              overflow: hidden; 
                              margin:10px;
                              margin-left:0px;
                              background: url('${videosList[i].thumbnail}'); 
                              background-size: cover; 
                              background-position-x: center; 
                              background-position-y: center;">
                                  <div style="position: absolute; 
                                    bottom:0px; 
                                    height:100px; 
                                    width:100%; 
                                    background: black; 
                                    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);"></div>
                                  <img src="https://www.ramiksadana.com/images/play.png" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; left:110px; top: 30px; margin:0!important;" />
                                  <p style="position: absolute; bottom:0px; color: white; margin: 0px 10px; margin-bottom: 15px !important; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; text-overflow-y: ellipsis;">
                                    ${videosList[i].title}
                                  </p>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                          <a href="${route}/${videosList[i].content_id}/${sourceLanguage}" target="_blank">
                            <div style="position: relative; 
                              width: 320px; 
                              height: 180px; 
                              border-radius: 8px;
                              overflow: hidden; 
                              margin:10px;
                              margin-left:0px;
                              background: url('${videosList[i].thumbnail}'); 
                              background-size: cover; 
                              background-position-x: center; 
                              background-position-y: center;">
                                  <div style="position: absolute; 
                                    bottom:0px; 
                                    height:100px; 
                                    width:100%; 
                                    background: black; 
                                    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);"></div>
                                  <img src="https://www.ramiksadana.com/images/play.png" style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; left:110px; top: 30px; margin:0!important;" />
                                  <p style="position: absolute; bottom:0px; color: white; margin: 0px 10px; margin-bottom: 15px !important; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; text-overflow-y: ellipsis;">
                                    ${videosList[i].title}
                                  </p>
                            </div>
                          </a>
     

  </div>


</div>
```

javascript code:

```
const flavoursContainer = document.getElementById("slider");
      const flavoursScrollWidth = flavoursContainer.scrollWidth;
      setInterval(() => {
        if (flavoursContainer.scrollLeft !== flavoursScrollWidth) {
          flavoursContainer.scrollTo(flavoursContainer.scrollLeft + 100, 0);
        }
      }, 1000);
```

Comment: `flavoursContainer.scrollLeft !== flavoursScrollWidth` is probably not a good condition to use. If this starts with `flavoursScrollWidth` being anything else but a multiple of 100, then you will probably never "hit" this condition.

Comment: _"However, the scrolling does not loop back to the first item when it reaches the last item."_ - you only have an `if` branch to keep it going ... So if you want to do something _else_ when your condition is not fulfilled, then why is there no `else` branch?

Comment: @CBroe sorry, I will edit my question. actually I did not have clue how to loop back to the first item.

Comment: Well the "moving back" part would be to set scrollLeft to 0 again, or call scrollTo with values 0, 0.